# moving from Zorin 12 to elementary OS juno

Tags: system-installation, release-juno

I have a Macbook pro that no longer runs OS X, I have Zorin 12 on it. I am trying to figure out how to install elementary on my Macbook. From elementary's website, I have 3 options to choose from my current operating system: Windows (download Rufus and make a Install Drive on a USB) Mac OS, and Ubuntu.

Since my Zorin OS is meant for Windows I tried to go the Rufus option, downloading its newest version 3.5. When I opened it (after downloading) it says "Unsupported Windows version, This version of Windows is no longer supported by Rufus".

I have already made up the elementary OS 5.0 Juno DVD. But following the instructions on their website isn't getting me anywhere because I do NOT have a Bootable USB drive. I have also tried other options to Rufus- like Pendrivelinux, but thats only seeming to frustrate me, too because I am not very tech saavy.

Does anyone know what to do or send me a link for a from anyone who has changed from Zorin OS to elementary OS -- and preferably with a Macbook?

thanks

Comment: Zorin OS is from the **Linux family**, you can follow the instructions for *Ubuntu* from the site I think. First download the elementary OS from the https://elementary.io and while verifying your download using that command from the installation page, remember to run that command where you downloaded file is stored. Let me know what you find.

Comment: **A bootable USB** is an USB device that you can use to install operating systems. You need to create one before installing an OS.

Comment: And please help me understand what do you mean by, "I have already made up the Elementary OS 5.0 Juno DVD"? If you have a elementary OS DVD, you can install the OS using it. You don't need to create another bootable media.

Comment: Response #1 of more.hey Hasan, I paid and downloaded E OS. the Verify download did not resemble what Elem has on their website. there was no *Sha256sum elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso and likewise, there was no Output repsonse like whats on Elem website. I did check it however and it gave me a report back that "File Integrity check was succefully and there seems to be no corrupt files on disk". UNetbootin downloaded but i dont have anything "Diskimage" that will open it. making me have to go find a way to open a bin.file.  by creating a CUE file and then trying to put that in the bin.file

Comment: thats where i am at now but not really being able to put that CUE file into the UNetbootin binary file. i can ususally figure things out, but ive been at this quite a while and making little progress. i might just take this to an IT person and they can probably do in 10mins what would take me all day. however, im very stubborn. ill take a break and come back to it. if that doesnt work, ill take it to someone who knows computers.

Comment: No, there will be no ***Sha256sum elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso** instead you will have **elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso** (which is a **disk image**). `sha256sum` is terminal command that helps you verify the download. Please open terminal in Zorin OS and execute `sha256sum elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso` to verify the download, output will be same as shown in elementary OS's website.

Comment: yes i opened the Zorin terminal and it says theres 'no such file or directory'. and thats the response i get while having the Elementary OS 5.0 Juno ISO burned to a dvd disk in my computer. these Walkthrough instructions are confusing for the lay person. i mean the WT instructions on Elementary's website.

Comment: Please take a look at the answer bellow, i think it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you basically want to install elementary OS replacing Zorin OS. Please follow the instructions bellow,

1. At first please download elementary OS from the official website. If you have downloaded already please go to next step.
2. After that please open the Zorin Menu and go to "Utilities" > "Terminal" and change directory to where you download files is by `cd <path to your dir>`. For example if you have that file in "Downloads" folder than you should execute `cd Downloads`.
3. Now please execute the command `sha256sum elementaryos-5.0-stable.20181016.iso` to verify the download. You will have exact output as shown in the elementary OS website which is, `a8c7b8c54aeb0889bb3245356ffcd95b77e9835ffb5ac56376a3b627c3e1950f`.
4. After that you need to install UNetbootin. To install execute these commands in the terminal one after one, you can also follow other instructions provided [in this page](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html). If you have installed already you can skip this step.
     `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`
     `sudo apt-get update`
     `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`
5. At this point please follow steps of using UNetbootbin from [elementary.io website](https://elementary.io/id/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium). Which goes as follows,

> - Open UNetbootin from the Dash. It will open a window like the one below:
> - **Select "Diskimage"**
> - **Click "…" to select the ISO that you downloaded previously.**
> - Unplug all USB memory devices apart from the one you want to use.
> - Click "OK" and wait for the process to finish.
>
> **Booting from the Install Drive**   In order to start the installation process, you must boot your computer from the install
>   drive.
>
> - Assuming that your computer is still on, start by inserting your install drive and restarting your computer.
> - Most computers will briefly allow you to change the boot order for this boot only by pressing a special key — usually <kbd>F12</kbd>, but
>     sometimes  <kbd>ESC</kbd> or another function key. Refer to the screen
>     or your computer's documentation to be sure.
> - Press <kbd>F12</kbd> (or the appropriate key) and select the install drive—usually "USB-HDD" or something containing the word
>     "USB", but the wording may vary. If you choose the incorrect drive,
>     your computer will likely continue to boot as normal. Just restart
>     your computer and pick a different drive in that menu.
> - Shortly after selecting the appropriate boot drive, you should be presented with the elementary OS splash screen. You may now follow the
>     on-screen instructions which will guide you through the rest of the
>     process.

Hope it helps.

Comment: 1st off, thanks for your help. secondly, please talk and go real slow. step 2 is already confusing me. i have opened Zorin menu and went to Terminal. now, nothing i can type or paste there gets me anywhere or anything i can understand. How exactly do i change the directory?

Comment: ok, progress. hold up, i'm on to step 4 atm.

Comment: alright, i have done all 5 of your steps. went back to Elementary steps on their page and installed UNetbootin. when i open UNetbootin it doesn't look anything like the pic it says it should. instead i get two windows that open, one right behide the other. the front one's header reads: RESTORE DISK IMAGE. and me the Image To Restore, the Image Size, and its Destination. NOW, the 2nd window behind it has the spec's for my whole hard drive. SO, is it wanting me to choose this whole hard drive to copy to, thus erasing my hard drive and Zorin and to then REPLACE it with E OS on my hard drive?

Comment: After installing and opening UNetbootin, can you please send a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: yes, but i am out of time for now. ill try and post back tonight/tomorrow. thanks

Comment: Cog, how do I upload a screenshot for you? Im not seeing an option on StackExchange to upload, unless i could set it as my Profile pic?

Comment: You can use https://imgbb.com/ and drop the link of the picture here in comments.

Comment: https://ibb.co/nD8xxDd

Comment: And that doesn't look like UNetBootbin to me, please cancel that and tell us if you face any difficulty. Also I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: morning Cog, here's where i am at. i didn't do any of you new steps in Step 5, I just restarted my computer. when it booted back up, it was using Elem OS. i tried to do a parallel install but it "Encountered an error copying files to the hard disk". it let me continue to function, so while using Ephiphone, i installed Mozilla. shortly after that i couldnt get back on to the internet, couldnt find mozilla and Ephiphone wouldn't load. so i rebooted my computer. all little gains i made- gone. this time around i tried to do a full install and format my whole drive. same result where it....

Comment: "encountered an error copying files to the hard drive". now i am wondering how to proceed next? should i now  go and do those new steps in Step 5 you wrote me and load UNetbootin from the Dash? and as i write you all this, its from Elementary OS, which looks so familar due to OS X.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92704/discussion-on-answer-by-cog-moving-from-zorin-12-to-elementary-juno). Please use this chat for further discussion, comment here only if you can't access the chat.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me and many outer users.
Please follow the instructions.
https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-install-linux-on-mac-3637265/